# JVM heap space usage

Tags: java, jvm

JVM heap space use rate is low, but FGC very frequently and use cpu 90%

> jstat -gcutil 16192 2000 10
>
> S0     S1    E  O  P   YGC   YGCT  FGC  FGCT   GCT
>
> 0.00 0.00 2.00 2.44  17.90  359  1.590 95458 26278.826 26280.416
>
> 0.00 0.00 2.01 2.44  17.90  359  1.590 95462 26279.650 26281.240
>
> 0.00 0.00 2.00 2.44  17.90  359  1.590 95469 26281.597 26283.187
>
> 0.00 0.00 2.00 2.44  17.90  359  1.590 95474 26283.263 26284.853
>
> 0.00 0.00 9.99 2.44  17.90  359  1.590 95474 26283.263 26284.853
>
> 0.00 0.00 4.00 2.44  17.90  359  1.590 95477 26284.121 26285.712
>
> 0.00 0.00 0.00 2.44  17.90  359  1.590 95479 26284.415 26286.005
>
> 0.00 0.00 2.00 2.44  17.90  359  1.590 95485 26286.163 26287.753
>
> 0.00 0.00 4.00 2.44  17.90  359  1.590 95486 26286.730 26288.321
>
> 0.00 0.00 4.00 2.44  17.90  359  1.590 95487 26287.011 26288.601

Anybody can tell me why？thanks！

Comment: Why do you think that's wrong?

Comment: jvm should FGC when O or P is full,now used very little,it is a tomcat nobody access it,but it use cpu 90%.

my eglish is not good,sorry!

Comment: Did you try the `-gccause` option? According to [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html): "This option displays the same summary of garbage collection statistics as the -gcutil option, but _includes the causes of the last garbage collection event and (if applicable) the current garbage collection event_. " - This might thus provide a hint as to the why.

Comment: the reason is system.gc()!thank you!

Comment: Glad that you could figure out your problem! :) Feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is probably calling System.gc(), try `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`

If this makes a difference, you need to find where it is being called.

Comment: @zgc with some luck you should be able to breakpoint `System.gc()` in your debugger to see where it is being called.